# Hook Scripts and Styles in WordPress

Tags: plugins, posts

As explained in [this page](http://www.wpexplorer.com/how-to-wordpress-custom-dashboard/), I have created a WordPress custom dashboard. Everthing works fine right now. But now I can't hook scripts and styles.

Here is my code for hooking scripts and styles.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',array(&$this,'register_scripts_styles'));
function register_scripts_styles(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_register_script( 'virtual-script', plugins_url('js/virtual-script.js', __FILE__));
wp_register_style('virtual-css',plugins_url('css/virtual.css',__FILE__));*/
 wp_enqueue_script( 'virtual-script');
wp_enqueue_style( 'virtual-css');

} //end registering scripts and styles
```

Comment: Don't use the wordpress.com tag, this tag is reserved for sites hosted on wordpress.com

Comment: okay.. I am new here..

Comment: No problem. Just a tip. :-)

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen Have you got my question?Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Use the alternate hook `admin_print_scripts-index.php` to load only on the Dashboard-Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two flaws in your code, one is a syntax error, the other one is the wrong hook.

Firstly, [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is the hook used to enqueue scripts and styles for **front end** use. When you need to enqueue scripts and styles for the backend, you should use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook

Secondly, you are missing a `/` in your file path

```
wp_register_script( 'virtual-script', plugins_url('js/virtual-script.js', __FILE__));
```

should be

```
wp_register_script( 'virtual-script', plugins_url('/js/virtual-script.js', __FILE__));
```

There is also some piece of code (`*/`) that doesn't belong in this line

```
wp_register_style('virtual-css',plugins_url('css/virtual.css',__FILE__));*/
```

This line should be

```
wp_register_style('virtual-css',plugins_url('/css/virtual.css',__FILE__));
```

I'm not sure if you are doing this in a class, but if you are not this `array(&$this,'register_scripts_styles'` is not necessary, you can just simply use `'register_scripts_styles'`

One last tip that you should consider when writing themes and plugins, is to use the build in debugging tool in wordpress. Most problems that you have should show up in debug. It also makes it easier to find a problem in a piece of code. Go and read through [Debugging Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Also take @bueltge comment into consideration here

Comment: I am doing this in a class @pieter

Comment: Ok, then stick with `$this`

Comment: okay thanks replying and suggesting me @Pieter Goosen :) I am working with your answer..

Comment: still I can't able to hook it in  dashboard.

Comment: Great, glad you got your problem solved. Enjoy :-)

Comment: I have one more doubt here.Did we need to hook jquery plugin with this scripts?

Comment: The correct way will be to deregister jquery first, and then enqueue it again in a plugin to make sure that if jquery is not loaded twice.

Comment: okay thanks !!.I want a popup form, for that I enqueued colorbox jquery plugin.But it is not working.It's really killing my time.

Comment: Have you checked the [colorbox support page](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: `wp_deregister_script('jquery');``wp_register_script( 'jquery-plugin', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');``wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );` Is this a correct way to deregister and enqueue it?

Comment: Don't enqueue the script from google. Only use the builtin script from wordpress, and you should dequeue, not deregister, jquery, so you should `wp_dequeue_script('jquery');`

Comment: Finally I fixed everthing and now the popup is working.Thanks for your help and guidance.Learned something from you.I am very happy now.Thank you !

Comment: My pleasure. ;-)